# Copy all files from S3 to ESB drive

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

Is there a way how to copy all files from S3 to an EBS drive belonging to a EC2 instance (which may belong to a a different AWS account than the S3)?

We are performing a migration of the whole account and upgrading the instances from t1 to t2 type and would like to backup the data from S3 somewhere outside S3 (and Glacier since Glacier is closely linked to S3) in case that something goes wrong and we lose the data.

I found only articles and docs talking about EBS snapshots but I am not sure if the S3 data can be actually copied to EBS (in some other way than manually).

According to [this](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) docs, I can ssh to my instance and copy the data from S3 buckets to my local EBS drive, but I have to specify the name of the bucket. Is there a way how to copy all the buckets there?

```
aws s3 sync s3://mybucket
```

I would like to achieve this:

Pseudocode:

```
for each bucket
 do
  aws s3 sync s3://bucketName bucketName
endfor
```

Is there a way how to do this using the AWS CLI?

Comment: If your goal is to back up S3, I think you're doing it wrong in the first place. Durability in S3 far exceeds durability of EBS, so much so that Amazon have introduced RRS (Reduced Redundancy Storage) as a cheaper option which is still good enough for most. [AWS guarantee your data for   99.999999999% durability](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2010/05/19/announcing-amazon-s3-reduced-redundancy-storage). I don't think you can feasibly replicate your data in a better way, since they replicate in sites across the globe.

Comment: Just to add to this, [here are results of a google search for EBS data loss on the AWS forums](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ebs+data+loss+site:forums.aws.amazon.com&safe=off&espv=2&sa=X&ved=0CDcQrQIoAzABahUKEwio96vHsNrGAhVOwIAKHfFzAMI&biw=1920&bih=992). I am not aware of any S3 data loss that wasn't caused by user/tool error, though I don't have any sources to back that up. While, anecdotally, EBS has improved in recent years, it has (also anecdotally) been known to suffer data loss.

Comment: Thanks for the tips but this backup is only meant as a short time backup-once the migration is over, this EBS will be deleted (and if everything goes well, we wont need it at all). It is meant for the case something goes wrong with S3 during account migration - Amazon does not say anything on this topic

Comment: @Mike, fwiw you're correct on S3's reliability but not its distribution.  S3 does not replicate user data outside the country where it is stored, unless cross-region replication to an alternate bucket is explicitly enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would agree with rdp-cloud's answer, but if you insist on creating EBS backups, to answer your question - there is no single aws cli command that would sync all available buckets in one go. You can use a bash script to get the list of all available buckets and then sync looping through them:

```
#!/bin/bash

BUCKETS=($(aws s3 ls | awk '{print $3}'))

for (( i=0; i<${#BUCKETS[@]}; i++ ))
do
  aws s3 sync s3://$BUCKETS[$i] <destination>
done
```

Make sure to test that `aws s3 ls | awk '{print $3}'` gives you the exact list you intend to sync before running the above.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3 is designed to provide 99.999999999% durability of objects over a given year and achieves this by automatically replicating the data you put into a bucket across 3 separate facilities (think datacenters), across Availability Zones, within a Region. This durability level corresponds to an average annual expected loss of 0.000000001% of objects. For example, if you store 10,000 objects with Amazon S3, you can on average expect to incur a loss of a single object once every 10,000,000 years. In addition, Amazon S3 is designed to sustain the concurrent loss of data in two facilities.

If you are still concerned about losing your data, you may consider copying the contents of the buckets into new buckets set up in another region. That means that you have your data in 1 system that offers 11x9's with a copy in another system that offers 11x9's. Say your original buckets reside in the Dublin region, create corresponding 'backup' buckets in the Frankfurt region and use the sync command.

eg.
aws s3 sync s3://originalbucket s3://backupbucket

That way you will have six copies of your data in six different facilities spread across Europe (naturally this is just as relevant if you use multiple regions in the US or ASIA). This would be a much more redundant configuration than pumping it into EBS volumes that have a meagre (when compared to S3) 99.999% availability. And better economics with S3 rates lower than EBS (1TB in S3 = US$30 vs 1TB in EBS(Magnetic) = US$50) and you only pay for the capacity you consume whereas EBS is based on what you provision.

Happy days...

References

http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/

http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/faqs/

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am not concerned about the data safety on S3 at all when it comes to normal situation. But can you tell me what happens to S3 when you migrate the whole account? Does Amazon guarantee that everything will go 100% smoothly? I haven't found any bullet proof answer to this. Therefor, I need to backup the data at least until the migration is over... I can rely on S3 after that withou any problems :)

Comment: What do you mean by "Migrate the Account"? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Smajl you can't migrate buckets across accounts.

Comment: That is not what I meant. We are migrating the whole account. We were using the old deprecated T1 instances and we are getting rid of them. In order to be able to create the new T2 instances, we have to migrate the account first, this should not affect the S3 storage since it mainly concerns EC2, nobody guaranteed to us, however, that something bad couldnt happen... And by "migrate", I mean transfer the whole aws account into another account (which supports T2 generation)

Comment: To clarify, you have an account that is EC2-Classic. You want to take advantage of the T2 range of instances so you intend to migrate to VPC. From my understanding, you should not be required to create a new account, simply create a VPC and raise the T2 instances as outlined here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/vpc-migrate.html